number of extermum, the opposite way
so this is a question i thought of when trying to draw something on desmos.
suppose a function $$a\cdot \sin(b(x+c))=f(x), \forall a,b,c\ne0$$, i choose this kind of function to keep the sine in it's regular wave form, and also we know that the derivative of this function has d vertexes over [-6,6], that $$x=-6\implies a\cdot \sin(b(x+c))=0$$ and that when the second derivative is equal to 0 the derivative is equal to $\pm1$ at how do i find the general expression for this function?
for $x=-6$ we plug it to the function and get $$a\cdot\sin(b(-6+c))=0\qquad /:a(\ne0)$$
$$\sin(b(c-6))=0 \qquad /\arcsin()$$
$$b(c-6)=\pi+2\pi n\quad n\in\mathbb{N} \qquad /:b(\ne0)$$
$$c-6=\frac{\pi }{b}\qquad /+6$$
i chose $2n\pi=0$ for not to much clutter
$$c=\frac{\pi }{b}+6$$
thus $$a\cdot \sin(b(x+\frac{\pi}{b}+6))=a\cdot \sin(bx+\pi+6b)$$
also
$$\frac{d}{dx}a\sin(bx+\pi+6b)=a\frac{d}{dx}\cos(bx+\pi+6b)=ab\cos(bx+\pi+6b)$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}a\sin(bx+\pi+6b)=\frac{d}{dx}ab\cos(bx+\pi+6b)=-ab^2\sin(bx+\pi+6b)$$
so when $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)=0$ $$-ab^2\cos(bx+\pi+6b)=0\qquad /:(-ab^2)(\ne0)$$
$$\cos(bx+\pi+6b)=0\qquad /\arccos()$$
$$bx+\pi+6b=\pi/2+2n\pi \qquad /-\pi-6b$$
choose $2n\pi=0$
$$bx=-\pi/2-6b\qquad /:b(\ne0)$$
$$x=-\frac{\pi/2+6b}{b}\qquad /:(-ab^2)$$
we plug into the first derivative and the equality
$$ab\sin(b(-\frac{\pi/2+6b}{b})+\pi+6b)=1$$
$$ab\sin(-\pi/2-6b+\pi+6b)=1$$
$$ab\sin(\pi/2)=1\qquad /:b$$
$$b=1/a$$
so $$f(x)=\frac{sin(bx+\pi+6b)}{b}$$
but what do i do with the d vertexes?

What do you mean with " d vertexes over [-6,6]"  d maxima, or d minima  or d/2  maxima and  minima? Why is f(-6)=0 since a is the amplitude it is independent of b  and c. so b=1/a makes no sense.

d/2 maxima and d/2 minima, i set f(-6)=0 to fit the range of my interval and showed that b=1/a from the condition that when f''(x)=0 f'(x)=1

On an interval of length 12 you have d/2 full periodes
so you have 24/d periodes which gives you b. b=1/a is wrong, again, a is the amplitude and has nothing to do with period or frequency.
